# Trigger a form action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code, I suppose it triggers an event called "anAction" instead of a default form-action. But I cannot find any further information on that attribute. Is it valid HTML or does it belong to a library?

```
<form id="my_form" action="" data-trigger="anAction">

...</form>
```

Comment: that is just a data-* attribute, some libraries like bootstrap will detect certain data-* attributes to automate some javascript functions.

Comment: `data-*` is HTML attribute naming standard to store custom data attributes. see guide [HTML data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *global attribute* called `data-*`

more info here:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes 
and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

seeing this code looks like there's the use of preventing the form to take the browser default `action` returning a function that than uses that `data-*` value to call somehing, probably like:

```
$('[data-trigger]').submit(function( ev ){
   ev.preventDefault();

   var myData = $(this).data('trigger'); // anAction
   // now probably it uses that value to perform something...

});
```

might be the `data-trigger` in your case is used by a plugin that listens for that specific attribute...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a part of this package: https://www.npmjs.org/package/trigger

Comment: Looks like I was half-wrong - it seems data-* is a generic tag that can be used by many libraries, not just the one I linked.